# Trying to edit html page using php DomDocument class, but neither any errors show up nor it adds <li> and <a> tags to my static page.

Tags: php, html

I am trying to edit my html file using php based on the user input. When i run the code it dose not give me any error but at the same time it does not make any changes to the file. 
Here is the PHP code. 
    `$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    //validate the document
    $doc->validateOnParse = true;
    //libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile('index.html');
    $doc->formatOutput = true;`

```
//navigating to the ul
$ul=$doc->getElementById('ul');
$href= "/".$account_number."/".$account_number."-".$profile_name.".html";
$element="Acctount_ID:".$account_number; 

$ul=$doc->getElementById('homeSubmenu'); 
//create the li
$li=$doc->createElement('li');
$new_li=$ul->appendChild($li); 
//create the link 
$a = $doc->createElement('a');
$new_ul= $new_li->appendChild($a);
$new_ul->setAttribute('href', $href );
$new_ul->setAttribute('target','joe'); 
$new_ul->setAttribute('title', $element); 

echo $doc->saveHTML();     

include('./index.html'); 

//end of the php. 
?>
```

Here is the html code.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <p>AWS Accounts</p>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-
expanded="true" class="">Accounts</a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled collapse in" id="homeSubmenu" aria-
expanded="true" style="">
                    <li><a href="report1/report.html" target="joe">Account 
ID: 930621594025</a></li>
                    <li><a href="report2/report-rahul.html" 
target="joe">Account ID: 725840360046</a></li>
                    <li><a href="report3/report-chenna.html" 
target="joe">Account ID: 624704405165</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: I've tried it with just the segment of HTML you've included and it does add in the code.  Is there another 'homeSubmenu' in the full HTML?

Comment: There is another homeSubmenu, but it is the link before the unordered list.<a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="">Accounts</a>